# Trying to get some script to move a pdf file into a folder based on first 4 characters of filename

Tags: file, batch-file, pdf, move

I am trying to move a list of `.pdf` files to folders based on the first `4` characters of said [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) files

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.pdf) do (
    echo file found  %%A
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
    for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
    echo folder name !folname!
    if not exist "!folname!" (
        echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
        md "!folname!"
    ) else (
        echo Folder !folname! exists
    )
    echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
    move "%%A" "!folname!"
)
echo Finished
pause
```

Comment: i am trying to move a list of pdf files to folders based on the first 4 characters of said pdf files -

Comment: You don't appear to be moving a list at all, just file system objects in the current directory one by one. Additionally you appear to be using an undetermined string length, _(all characters up to the first underscore in the file name)_, not `4`. I have added your comment above into your question, so you can delete the comment above then [add the information that is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57058485/edit) to create an on topic question. You need to provide a specific single replicable issue and fully explain your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To move all `.pdf` files in the current directory into directories named using the first four characters of their basename, here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example, *(without all of the unnecessary screen output)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%A In (*.pdf)Do (Set "fN=%%~nA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    RoboCopy . "!fN:~,4!" "%%A" /Mov>NUL
    EndLocal)
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

You could probably even do it as a single line command.

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@For %%A In (*.pdf)Do @Set "fN=%%~nA"&Call RoboCopy . "%%fN:~,4%%" "%%A" /Mov>NUL
```

From a single [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) instance:

```bat
For %A In (*.pdf)Do @Set "fN=%~nA"&Call RoboCopy . "%fN:~,4%" "%A" /Mov>NUL
```

Please note that the ideas presented above assume that your `.pdf` basenames do not contain any exclamation marks/points and that `Robocopy.exe` exists in the current directory or within the locations specified under `%PATH%`.

*Please also note that the 4th character in your basenames should not be a space or period, as the Windows shell and user interface does not support those.*